# iOS URL scheme twitter://user?screen_name=SCREEN_NAME not working anyomre

Tags: ios, twitter, url-scheme

I want to redirect the user of our iOS App to our Twitter profile page with the URL scheme:
`twitter://user?screen_name=SCREEN_NAME`

I recently noticed that this opens the Twitter app as expected but it shows a screen as if I used it for the first time:

[image: Twitter error]

The app is also completely frozen, I can't touch anything. If I keep the app open and klick on the UIButton in our app again, the profile will be shown correctly but still without being able to touch anything.

The only way I can get this to work is if I start the Twitter app before and let it open (in background). If I select the UIButton in our app now, everything works fine, the profile is shown and I'm able to interact with the Twitter app.

I think that there might be a problem of the Twitter app to handle such URL schemes on app start, but works when the app is already running.

Does anyone else experience this problem or have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly deleting and reinstalling the Twitter app fixed this problem. Still don't know why it happened though...

Comment: A possible issue could be iOS updates from say iOS7 to iOS8 require the app to re-register its URL scheme. Will check back when iOS9 comes out. This worked for me.